# I want to get the value of my json uri parameter

Tags: php, json, url

I want to get the value of PARAMS in my url

```
app-rolly.lan.beestripe.privsub.net/t/e/?callback=callback&aid=13&alias=PxTRvtD9vCJN0VpmgQlNhtR1d5Ec&ua=chrome-Windows&event=result-click-ad&cb=1476946609765&params=%7B"search_source"%3A"toolbar"%2C"test_id"%3A2%7D
```

Comment: question need to add some more clarification. from where you get this, and what is expected outcome you want from this? Also what you have tried so for?

Comment: i just run the url to get something like this 
params : '{"search_source":"toolbar","test_id":2}'

Comment: do you want something like this:- https://eval.in/665245

Comment: $ARRAY = json_decode($result,true); you will get the array value you can access like this ECHO $ARRAY['search_source'];

Comment: thanks for theanswer

Comment: if my answer is useful mark it with green tick it useful to future use reference @ZacharyCampaner

Answer (score 0):

Those all json data you just decode it into array using `json_decode()`

```
$ARRAY = json_decode($result,true);
```

you will get the array value you can access like this

```
echo $ARRAY['search_source'];
```

**Example :**

```
<?php

$result = '{"search_source":"toolbar","test_id":2}';

$ARRAY = json_decode($result,true);

echo $ARRAY['search_source'];

 ?>
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
toolbar
```